# Unable to loop form fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

In models.py,I created a character type field called "category".After the user enters the category name,it is saved in the database and now I want to display all the category names stored in the database.I created four category names.I can see all four in the database but when displaying it in the UI, I see NONE instead of the category names.
views.py,

```
def add_cat(request):
    form = CatForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form":form}

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        category = form.cleaned_data.get("category")
        instance.category = category
        instance.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Category Added')
    return render(request,"add-cat.html",context)
```

forms.py,

```
class CatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Add_cat
        fields = ['category']
```

My template file,

```
{% extends "admin-menu.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Add Category</h2>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table align="center">
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" style="margin-left: 48%;"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>    
    </form>

    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages" style="list-style-type: none;">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    &nbsp
    <form id="id1">
    {% for field in form %}
        <table align="center">
            <tr><th>Category Name</th></tr>   
            <tr><td>{{field.value}}</td></tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing here. You display the form once with `form.as_table`, and then again by looping through and doing `field.value`. But the fields won't have a value; if you want to display what's already saved in the database, you should be querying the model, not the form.

Comment: First I creating a input box for creating a category and then in the second table I am trying to display it in the browser and I am getting None instead of field value.

Comment: Because as I said, *you need to query the model*, not display the form fields again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
def add_cat(request):
    form = CatForm(request.POST or None)
    catagories = <model>.objects.all()
    context = {"form":form, 'categories':categories}

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        category = form.cleaned_data.get("category")
        instance.category = category
        instance.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Category Added')
    return render(request,"add-cat.html",context)
```

In templates

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <table align="center">
        <tr><th>Category Name</th></tr>   
        <tr><td>{{ category }}</td></tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is displaying the categories only when the request method is POST(Only when I add new items),but when I just navigating through diffrent menu items(GET request) I am getting empty table.

Comment: Add the following two line after context
catagories = <model>.objects.all()
    context.update({'categories':categories})

I'll update the answer as well